# WCF / WIF - Should I find claims in the backend?

Tags: wcf, wif, claims-based-identity

I have an ASP.NET application calling a WCF service.
In ASP.NET application, I make a call to ADFS to perform authentication and I can see all the claims of the user in CurrentPrincipal. Then I perform the call of the WCF service (wsHttpBinding), but the list of claims is empty.

What could be the reason?

Comment: WS2007FederationHttpBinding?

Answer (score 3):

If I'am not mistake there different ways to get Claims in WCF.

**Thread.CurrentPrincipal** - Simple and easy to used but need some setting in your configuration, which is most neglected.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Test.Services.WifBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true" />
        <!---Set principalPermissionMode to always to pass the ClaimsIdentity info to the Thread.CurrentPrincipal-->
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always"/>
    </behavior>
  <serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**OperationContext.Current.ClaimsPrincipal** - I can't remember if this needs some configuration but I guess you can get it directly from method invoked.

**OperationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.AuthorizationContext.ClaimSets** - [Create a Custom Authorization Manager for a Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731774%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and need to add in config.

Note that I used Windows Identity Foundation (WIF).